# Drag LinearLayout Up And Down Only

Tags: java, android, android-layout, drag-and-drop, android-linearlayout

I need to be able to drag a LinearLayout containing a TextView up and down only.

The LinearLayout is a child of a RelativeLayout.

Here is my layout file:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MainActivity">





        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/drag"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#55000000"
            >


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="The Quick Brown Fox Jumped!!"
        android:padding="15dp"
        />
        </LinearLayout>





</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the code i tried.

```
 LinearLayout dragqueen;
 dragqueen = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drag);

  findViewById(R.id.drag).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        int prevX,prevY;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View v,final MotionEvent event)
        {
            final FrameLayout.LayoutParams par=(FrameLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                {
                    par.topMargin+=(int)event.getRawY()-prevY;
                    prevY=(int)event.getRawY();
                    par.leftMargin+=(int)event.getRawX()-prevX;
                    prevX=(int)event.getRawX();
                    v.setLayoutParams(par);
                    return true;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                {
                    par.topMargin+=(int)event.getRawY()-prevY;
                    par.leftMargin+=(int)event.getRawX()-prevX;
                    v.setLayoutParams(par);
                    return true;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {
                    prevX=(int)event.getRawX();
                    prevY=(int)event.getRawY();
                    par.bottomMargin=-2*v.getHeight();
                    par.rightMargin=-2*v.getWidth();
                    v.setLayoutParams(par);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

i have no idea how to achieve this. I copied the Drag and Drop code from a tutorial on the web.....

Answer (score 2):

I haven't messed with this before, and you didn't really state a problem, but I am gonna go on a limb and assume that at the moment you can drag it in all directions, whereas you only want it to be draggable on a vertical axis.

That being said, I am looking through your code and seeing many places where the x axis is being changed. Wherever the leftMargin is changed is where the code is moving on the horizontal axis.

Try this, and see if this does what you want:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View v,final MotionEvent event)
    {
        final FrameLayout.LayoutParams par=(FrameLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
        switch(event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                par.topMargin+=(int)event.getRawY()-prevY;
                prevY=(int)event.getRawY();
                v.setLayoutParams(par);
                return true;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                par.topMargin+=(int)event.getRawY()-prevY;
                v.setLayoutParams(par);
                return true;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                prevY=(int)event.getRawY();
                par.bottomMargin=-2*v.getHeight();
                v.setLayoutParams(par);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Let me know if this works for you,
Joseph Meadows